# How do I expire a django template cache key on receiving a signal?

Tags: django, caching, templates

In my front page template I use the cache function like this:

```
{% cache 86400 my_posts %}
    {% get_latest_posts %}
{% endcache %}
```

When there is a new post I would like to expire the cache key; like this:

```
def clear_post_cache():
    cache.delete('my_posts')

post_save.connect(clear_post_cache, sender=Post)
```

My problem is that the cache key isn't accessible as 'my_posts'. How do I find the key name?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at how the cache key is [constructed](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/templatetags/cache.py#L27):

```
args = md5_constructor(u':'.join([urlquote(resolve_variable(var, context)) for var in self.vary_on]))
cache_key = 'template.cache.%s.%s' % (self.fragment_name, args.hexdigest())
```

The key is a combination of the fragment name (`my_posts`) and a md5 sum of additional arguments to the cache tag. Since you don't have additional arguments, the hexdigest is `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` (the md5 hash of the empty string). The cache key should therefore end up to be

```
template.cache.my_posts.d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

If you need a more general solution, [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1593/) might help.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the `md5_constructor` in the first line of Benjamin Wohlwend's example above is deprecated. Current (Nov. 2011) version is:

```
args = hashlib.md5(u':'.join([urlquote(resolve_variable(var, context)) for var in self.vary_on]))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.core.cache.utils import make_template_fragment_key

cache.delete(make_template_fragment_key('footer'))
```